# AVMutableComposition Upside down video export

Tags: ios, swift2, avfoundation, video-processing

I am trying to make `AVPlayer` to play an slow motion video. So I used `AVMutableComposition`. It plays the video in slow motion but the problem is that the output video is upside down.

Comment: Hi, is there a way to play slow motion videos using with AVPlayer? I tried but it just plays at normal speed. I tried setting the player.rate to 0.2 but somehow it is not really as slow as the slow motion video I took from my iPhone 6. Tried setting it to a lower rate but it doesn't seem to slow even more. Or do I really need to use AVMutableComposition?

Comment: Please have a look at the [tour] and the [help]. You will see, among other important informations, that you can [edit] your question after it has been posted. This way you will be able to include additional information instead of posting in comments.

Comment: Is these video shot by iPhone or they are mp4s?